# Node Buffer to JSON

Tags: node.js, json, string, file, buffer

When I read a JSON file, parse, and output it, I only get some random numbers instead of my JSON file:

```
{
  type: 'Buffer',
  data: [
    123, 0,  34, 0,  83, 0,  99, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0,
    109, 0,  97, 0,  86, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 115, 0,
    105, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0,  34, 0,  58, 0,  49, 0,
     55, 0,  48, 0,  54, 0,  44, 0,  34, 0,  67, 0,
    104, 0, 105, 0, 108, 0, 100, 0,  65, 0,  99, 0,
     99, 0, 111, 0, 117, 0, 110, 0, 116, 0, 115, 0,
     34, 0,  58, 0, 123, 0,  34, 0,  83, 0,  45, 0,
     49, 0,  45, 0,  53, 0,  45, 0,  50, 0,  49, 0,
     45, 0,  50, 0,
    ... 52404 more items
  ]
}
```

I load and output it with this code:

```
contents = fs.readFileSync(filename);
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contents)))
```

I searched for this already but found no working solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not random numbers, it's a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). If you want to convert that buffer to a string (so you can parse the JSON into objects and such), you have to do that on purpose, since text is meaningless unless you know what encoding is used for the text (UTF8, Windows1252, etc.). [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) has an `encoding` option you can supply to tell it to convert the data to string using a given encoding, or you can use [`toString`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) on the `Buffer`.

Alternatively, if you're using [CJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (Node's original kind), they let you read JSON directly via [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id), parsing automatically.

---

In a comment you've said:

> Ok I used toString() on it and then another error appears: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1. To add an encoding does nothing. The file is UTF-8.

That's a separate issue, but:

Since `JSON.parse` counts from position 0 (at least in Node.js, I don't think that's dictated by the spec), that tells us either the JSON is invalid, or there's a byte order mark at the beginning of the file not being handled by the encoding.

Sometimes editors put a BOM at the beginning of UTF-8 files. You can check to see if that's what's going on like this:

```
let text = yourBuffer.toString("utf8");
if (text.codePointAt(0) === 0xFEFF) { // UTF8 BOM
    text = text.substring(1);
}
```

Then you should be able to use `JSON.parse` on `text`.

Comment: Ok I used `toString()` on it and then another error appears: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1`. To add an encoding does nothing. The file is UTF-8

Comment: @programmer - I've moved the comment that I had here into the end of the answer with a bit of code that may help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I implemented it right but It changes nothing. It also says as an error that `{ is undefined`. Then I watched at the text that should be parsed and I realized that between every character is a space. It looks like this: `{ " k e y " : " v a l u e " }`

Comment: @programmer - Your file is not in UTF8. Looks like it might be in UTF-16-LE, if the "spaces" are actually character 0.

Comment: I looked up the encoding using `file *` and got `data`. But it throws an error if I put data in?